# PostgreSQL - How to update nested JSONB elements

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-12

I found some information, but some of it was not clearly explained or the examples were incomprehensible.
This example was successfully executed on PostgreSQL 12. The requirement is to partially change a JSON structure with PostgreSQL. JSONB is used as data type.

The data structure has the following appearance

```
{
   "id":1,
   "person":{
      "name":"fred"
   }
}
```

The data record is to be changed. The property `$.person.name` has to be changed and `$.person.gender` will be added.

```
select '{"id":1, "person" : {  "name" : "fred" } }'::jsonb || '{"person": { "name" : "lisa", "gender" : "F" }}'::jsonb
```

The result contains the corresponding modifications.

```
{
   "id":1,
   "person":{
      "name":"lisa",
      "gender":"F"
   }
}
```

The update statement for the JSONB column `data` looks like this

```
update t_person set data = data || '{"person": { "name" : "lisa", "gender" : "F" }}'::jsonb
```

Comment: Look at Brendan Graetz blog https://blog.bguiz.com/2017/json-merge-postgresql/ for a resursive json merge. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just reset the whole `person` attribute with `jsonb_set()`:

```
select jsonb_set(
    '{"id":1, "person" : { "name" : "fred" } }'::jsonb,
    '{person}',
    '{ "name":"lisa", "gender":"F" }'::jsonb
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=543dc451700e18c6653849e75453bd29)**:

```
| jsonb_set                                            |
| :--------------------------------------------------- |
| {"id": 1, "person": {"name": "lisa", "gender": "F"}} |
```